# FILE has no members _ptr/_base when building sox with UCRT version of MinGW-w64

Tags: c, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

In sox (current version is 14.4.2) there is a function `static void UNUSED rewind_pipe(FILE * fp)` in `src\formats.c` that rewinds a `FILE *` handle to a pipe by doing `fp->_ptr = fp->_base;`.

However when compiling with MinGW-w64 built against UCRT this fails as in `stdio.h` the definition of `FILE` is:

```c
  struct _iobuf {
#ifdef _UCRT
    void *_Placeholder;
#else
    char *_ptr;
    int _cnt;
    char *_base;
    int _flag;
    int _file;
    int _charbuf;
    int _bufsiz;
    char *_tmpfname;
#endif
  };
  typedef struct _iobuf FILE;
```

So `FILE` has no members `_ptr` and `_base` when `_UCRT` is defined.

Is there another way to achieve the same functionality, so sox can be built with MinGW-w64 against UCRT?

Comment: The comments say this function is optional, and can be made empty. You'll only lose format autodetection for pipes.

Comment: True, but I was till wondering if MinGW-w64 can rewind a pipe at all. If so then detecting the audio file type can still be made to work when piping data to sox.

Comment: Not sure, but seems [MSYS2](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-sox/0001-ucrt-no-rewind-pipe.patch) also choose to disable this function.

Comment: `fseek` is supposed to do this. Maybe mocking this rewind function with a fseek call is an option?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't seek pipe streams...